# Why is onPeersAvailable called many times

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I use wi fi direct to connect devices. I want to connect to available devices and show them in a list. But why is onPeersAvailable called many times? I don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're in discovery mode.  YOu're constantly looking for new peers.  To stop looking, call stopPeerDiscovery.